# How to call Jquery Plugin function from outside of plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using asp.net mvc application.
From last 2 days i am trying and following some Internet solutions to call the MyPlugin function from outside the JS .
Please help me to find what wrong i am doung.

I had added myplugin JS and written some lines of code  and now i am trying to access that function from View script.

**My View :**

```
<head>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/MyPlugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divMain" >
  </div>
</body>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#divMain").MyPlugin();

 });
</script>
```

**MyPlugin JS:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyPlugin= function () {
        alert("ready to start!!!!");
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**And This message i got :**

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).MyPlugin is not a function"

Please help me to find a solution of this problem. I want to call that Plugin's function.

Comment: I can see that you have not added jQuery on your page.. Please add it before your plugin js and try.

Comment: The code you've shown works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ke6sy8ux/. Have you debugged this at all? Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: OK Thanks @RoryMcCrossan , let me check it again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add jquery prior to your plugin js.

```
<head>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/MyPlugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divMain" >
  </div>
</body>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#divMain").MyPlugin();

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Manprit , I have just tried and getting same error. I have updated my question again.

Comment: The code works fine for me. May be clearing cache can help you.

Comment: This is too odd. i  have tried with new project and its not working for me. code and everything is ok but not getting where is the actual problem

Comment: Yes . I got error message
`jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).MyPlugin is not a function

    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Example:57)

    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: Add debugger before `$.fn.MyPlugin= function () {` and see if hits your debugger

Comment: i just checked and its hitting to `$.fn.MyPlugin= function() {` on page load.

Comment: After it is called, just write $.fn.MyPlugin in developer console to verify that your plugin is registered! It should return a function

Comment: Yes..!!!! Solved. The main reason was my Layout page. The Jquery bundle was execute after my JS Plugin so i faced this problem.